# UIView gets behind another UIView iPad/iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have the root View which is the default view that comes in with the nib file.  In that view I have a Image for the background and two other views:

[image]

and in the simulator the ViewMain contains:  (I made the alpha of the other view = 0 to show that view)

[image]

and when I make the alpha of the ViewValor1 = 1 I get:

[image]

this view contains a page but everything else is still on the background.

WHY IS IT THAT SOMETIMES THE VIEWMAIN GET SEND TO THE TOP???

[image]

How can I prevent that from happening? I have noticed that that happens only when I rotate the device first several times and then change the alpha of ViewValor1. Maybe I should set that view to be on the top before making it's alpha equal to 1. how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever there is refresh in the view, move that background view to background by `[viewMain sendSubviewToBack:viewValor];`